# angularjs - storing table view filters in url

Tags: angularjs

I have a table view with a form above it for doing advanced search (text fields, date ranges, drop down lists etc.)

I am trying to store this state in the URL using `$location.search('filters', angular.toJson($scope.filters)); but was wondering if there is a better way.

The reason I want to make use of the URL is so people can share links to filtered data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid use case for `$location.search`, but you don't need to do an `angular.toJson`. [`$location.search`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search) accepts an object as its parameter and will automatically convert it into an encoded query string before applying it to the URL.

Comment: Great. I was doing this $location.search('filters', $scope.filters)); instead of $location.search($scope.filters); which is why it was creating a weird looking URL.